# create self-signed certificate VPN

Tags: networking, active-directory, certificate, vpn, self-signed

I have a network consisting of two servers an active directory server(192.168.0.3) and a file server(192.168.0.7) I need to create a self-signed certificate using the active directory server to enable domain users to access the file server

does anyone know the best configuration I tried most of the ways mentioned on the internet and I was not able to figure out the right way

Answer (score 2):

For creating **SSL** certificates and Installing the Certificate Authority (CA) you can also use this [link](https://www.javaxt.com/wiki/Tutorials/Windows/How_to_Enable_LDAPS_in_Active_Directory), you can follow the step by step procedure.

For accessing your file server you need in the same IP segment to sharing the same network prefix as defined by their IP addresses and the network mask, and also verify most normal FTP servers use port 21, **SFTP** servers use port 22 and **FTP** over **TLS** (implicit mode) use port 990 by default. These ports are not mandatory, however, so it's best to allow outgoing connections to arbitrary remote ports.